# Concatenate each object property values of javascript array , properties are list of strings in javascript

Tags: javascript

i have array of objects need to convert to new array with new property using another list of strings to read the property in javascript.

var output =

```
[
 {Id: '000000CayeAAC', Name: 'KCP13', FTA: 'LOS', FTN: 'M'}
 {Id: '000000CayLAAS', Name: 'KCN15', FTA: 'DC', FTN: 'M'}
 {Id: '000000CaxXAAS', Name: 'KCA21', FTA: 'AUS', FTN: 'M'}
 {Id: '000000CaxCAAS', Name: 'KCZ43', FTA: 'CA', FTN: 'M'}
]
```

var mypropertylist = ['Name','FTA','FTN'];

**i want to new array is like below**

var newArray =

```
 [ 
  {value: '000000CayeAAC', concatName: 'KCP13 - LOS - M'}
  {value: '000000CayLAAS', concatName: 'KCN15 - DC - M'}
  {value: '000000CaxXAAS', concatName: 'KCA21 - AUS - M'}
 ]
```

i tried this way

```
output.map(item=>{
                    
                    this.newArray  = [...this.newArray,
                                            {value:item.Id, 
                                             concatName:item.Name + ' - '+item.FTA+ ' - '+item.FTN}];
```

i got desired output but i want to get dynamically by using `mypropertylist`

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Why `KCZ43` disapear ?

Comment: sorry i added only 3. 4th should also come same as others

Comment: Related: [How to concatenate two string fields into one in a JavaScript array?](/q/34576386/4642212), [How to concatenate multiple properties of same element from an array?](/q/69056356/4642212).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that ?

```js
const output = 
  [ { Id: '000000CayeAAC', Name: 'KCP13', FTA: 'LOS', FTN: 'M' } 
  , { Id: '000000CayLAAS', Name: 'KCN15', FTA: 'DC',  FTN: 'M' } 
  , { Id: '000000CaxXAAS', Name: 'KCA21', FTA: 'AUS', FTN: 'M' } 
  , { Id: '000000CaxCAAS', Name: 'KCZ43', FTA: 'CA',  FTN: 'M' } 
  ] 

const concatFunction = (arr, ...items) =>
  arr.map(({Id,...elms}) =>
    ({ value: Id
     , concatName: items.map( item => elms[item] ).join(' - ') 
    })
  )

console.log( concatFunction( output, 'Name', 'FTA', 'FTN' ))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
.as-console-row::after { display: none !important; }
```

Comment: Your answer would benefit from an explanation of what your code is doing.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it, the property list is a list of keys whose values should be concatenated to form `concatName`.  Let's do that just that property manipulation first...

```
// return a string containing the values of props in object, concatenated 
function concatValues(object, props) {
  const values = props.map(prop => object[prop]);
  return values.join(' - ');
}
```

Next we need a thing that transforms the object, changing the Id prop and using the concatValues...

```
// return an object with it's Id renamed and it's props concatenated
function transform(object, props) {
  return { value: object.Id, concatName: concatValues(object, props) }
}
```

Then, just map that over the input.  Demo...

```js
// return a string containing the values of props in object, concatenated 
function concatValues(object, props) {
  const values = props.map(prop => object[prop]);
  return values.join(' - ');
}

// return an object with it's Id renamed and it's props concatenated
function transform(object, props) {
  return { value: object.Id, concatName: concatValues(object, props) }
}

const arrayA = [
 {Id: '000000CayeAAC', Name: 'KCP13', FTA: 'LOS', FTN: 'M'},
 {Id: '000000CayLAAS', Name: 'KCN15', FTA: 'DC', FTN: 'M'},
 {Id: '000000CaxXAAS', Name: 'KCA21', FTA: 'AUS', FTN: 'M'},
 {Id: '000000CaxCAAS', Name: 'KCZ43', FTA: 'CA', FTN: 'M'}
];

const mypropertylist = ['Name','FTA','FTN'];
const arrayB = arrayA.map(el => transform(el, mypropertylist))
console.log(arrayB);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var output = [
 {Id: '000000CayeAAC', Name: 'KCP13', FTA: 'LOS', FTN: 'M'},
 {Id: '000000CayLAAS', Name: 'KCN15', FTA: 'DC', FTN: 'M'},
 {Id: '000000CaxXAAS', Name: 'KCA21', FTA: 'AUS', FTN: 'M'},
 {Id: '000000CaxCAAS', Name: 'KCZ43', FTA: 'CA', FTN: 'M'}
];

var newArray = output.map(item => {
    return {Id: item.Id, concatName: [item.Name, item.FTA, item.FTN].join(" - ")};
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).